# How to open proxy port in windows-server's wirewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, proxy

I have some proxies which is working well in my local machine but when I goes to use this same proxy in `windows-server` its showing `connection time out`.

is there any setting in firewall for proxy? are we need to open any proxy port in server's firewall?

Comment: Which port is the proxy using?

Comment: I am using "7866" port in proxy.

Comment: Then, as it's a completely non-standard port, you may actually have to open it in your server's firewall; give it a try and see if it works...

Comment: where firewall contains this port setting are you know?